# WAMP router/crossbar.io behind NGiNX proxy?

Tags: crossbar, wamp-protocol

How can I setup crossbar.io router/WAMP router behind NGiNX reverse proxy?

Comment: Sorry this is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Nginx to **forward WebSocket** on the respective port. For a default Crossbar.io node configuration, this is (non-secure) WebSocket on port 8080. Check [this](http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/).